# Component's onChange function being passed the last parameter value when the ReactJS components are rendered from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick, antd

I have an array of objects based on which i generate an array of ReactJS components.

These then get rendered in the render method. The code in short is as follows,

### getComponents() :

```
f = [{name: 'Input1', colSpan: 5}, {name: 'Input2', colSpan: 10}];
var renderedComponents = [];

for(i=0;i < f.length;i++){

 var name = f.name;
 var colSpan = f.colSpan;

 renderedComponents.push(
      <Col span={colSpan} key={i} style={{marginRight: 5}}>
        <FormItem {...fieldbounds} {...fieldparams}>
          <Input
          onChange={(e)=> {this.inputChange(name, e)}}
          />
        </FormItem>
      </Col>
    );
  }

return renderedComponents;
```

### onChange Handler:

```
inputChange = (n,e) => {
  console.log(n);
}
```

### render():

```
render(){
    return(<div>{this.getComponents()}</div>);
}
```

When the components render, i get two text boxes. But when changing the values in the text boxes, i get a console log of 'Input2' even when i change Input1.

Looks like the name attribute is given the last value of the f array when it is rendered.

### Current behavior:

> - Changing text in Input1 has a console log of 'Input2'
> - Changing text in Input2 has a console log of 'Input2'

### Expected behavior:

> - Changing text in Input1 has a console log of 'Input1'
> - Changing text in Input2 has a console log of 'Input2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the expected behavior when replacing the fat arrow function in onChange with the following code.

```
onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this, name)}
```

Can someone help me understand why .bind works while the fat arrow function does not?

Comment: The arrow is an ES6 syntax, which is a direct replacement for using function(). You have to independently bind the functions always, and this is not related to the arrow operator.